# How to get SelectDateWidget in Django to show different "Year" options

Tags: html, django, django-forms

```
class PersonalForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = InfoPersonal
        widgets = {'dateofbirth' :  SelectDateWidget()}
```

Just the simple implementation gives a dropdown for the Year starting from 2011. I would rather have my users not be newborn babies. How do I customize this ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can pass `years` argument wiith list of years in any order. For example

```
SelectDateWidget(years=range(1950, 2012))
```

Comment: Also would you know how to remove that "Non-option" that comes in the drop down as in I would like it to open with Jan 1 1900?

Comment: @Sussagittikasusa You can add `defalut=%yourdate%` to `dateofbirth` field of your model. Or, if it's only for this form (or you don't want default value in model), you can override form's `__init__` method, setting initial: `self.fields['dateofbirth'].initial = %yourdate%`